# Rolling Resistance Coefficient

Tags: classical-mechanics, friction, simulations, rotation

I found that rolling resistance can be expressed with this equation:

$$F_\mathrm{rr} = \frac{C_\mathrm{rr} W}{r}$$

Where

$C_\mathrm{rr} =$ coefficient of rolling resistance

$W =$ normalforce

$r =$ wheel radius

What I don't know, tho, is how to calculate the coefficient of rolling resistance. At the first moment if may feel like being constant, but it actually isn't. It depends from multiple things. I am currently able to calculate what the slip ratio factor comes from wheels and from the surface. Normal street tires on asphalt surface will have 0.014 factor. However, the rolling resistance is also affected by car's velocity(in a game-friendly approximation). However, I don't know how.

Comment: OK! However, I have a problem here - I need to know if the $W$ takes wheel mass($Mwheel$), car total mass($Mcar$) or the exact load on wheel($(c/L)*Mcar$). If I don't know, I can't calculate it right...

Oh, anc inclined plane is relative to gravity direction or relative to car's downwards direction?

Comment: Hm... Doesn't sound right... Especially when calculating it per-wheel. I am kind of thinking that it may use load(the part of car weight that lies on exact wheel, it depends on the wheel longitudal distance from CG and is affected by acceleration producing what's called `weight transfer`). So what I am kind of trying to find out is - does it depend on $Wwheel$ or $Wload + W wheel$. From your answer I can expect that it might rather be the second version?

Comment: Updated question a bit.